# bluetooth communication between android app and c# windows form app

Tags: c#, android, .net, bluetooth, 32feet

I am using Bluetooth communication between an Android app and a C# Windows form app. The Android app works as a client and the C# app as a server. I can handle only on connection on the server (laptop) and when I disconnect and try to connect again nothing seems to be happening. I think that the client side works properly because I haved tested it with another mobile and the bug is in server code.

This is the server code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Thread connectserver;
    Stream mstream;
    BluetoothClient client;
    BluetoothListener bluelisten;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (serverstart)
        {
            updateui("server already started");
        }
        connectasserver();
    }

    private void connectasserver()
    {
         connectserver=new Thread(new ThreadStart (serverconnectedthread));
        connectserver.Start();

    }
    Guid muuid = new Guid("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    bool serverstart = false;
    public void serverconnectedthread()
    {
        serverstart = true;
        updateui("waiting for connections of clients\n");
         bluelisten = new BluetoothListener(muuid);
        bluelisten.Start();
        client = new BluetoothClient();
         client = bluelisten.AcceptBluetoothClient();
        updateui("client has connected\n");
        mstream=client.GetStream();

        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] recieved = new byte[1024];
                mstream.Read(recieved, 0, recieved.Length);

                updateui("recieved: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recieved));
                byte[] sent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(" hello world\n");
                mstream.Write(sent, 0, sent.Length);
            }
            catch(IOException except)
            {

                updateui("client has been disconnected\n");
                connectserver.Abort();
                client.Close();
                mstream.Flush();
                break;
            }
       }

    }

    private void updateui(string mess)
    {
        Func<int> del = delegate()
        {
            textbox3.AppendText(mess + System.Environment.NewLine);
            return 0;
        };
        Invoke(del);

    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox3_TextChanged()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Your question does not seem clear enough, do you mean you would have to restart the c# software after disconnecting for you to connect again?

Comment: I want after I didconnected first device connected yo server to connect again with the same device or othet device and this doesn't happen with  this  code. This code only can have one connect with it and after I disconnect it ,it can't listen to any other connection from any other device or the same device

Comment: Which error do u get when u try to listen for connection the second time?

Comment: I got no error but i couldn't listen for any other connection (only the first connection)

Answer (score 1):

catch(IOException except)
            {

```
            updateui("client has been disconnected\n");
            connectserver.Abort();
             severstart = false;      // add this line to the catch block.
            client.Close();
            mstream.Flush();
            break;
        }
```

Set severstart  equal to false so that it does not assume it has already started server.

Comment: bool serverstart is only dedicatated for printing "server is already running".it have no effect on any other lines of code except th is line  updateui("server already started");

Comment: What about the line return 0. What does it do?

Comment: It is the return value of the delgate because it returns <int>